# PHP if/else and AND/OR to check mandatory and optional fields

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I have eight input fields in my form that I need to check whether they are empty. Four of these are text fields, the other four are list boxes. When the user submits the form, the four text boxes need to be filled. The fifth field is a Yes/No selection. If the selection in this field is "No", then the remaining three can be left blank. However, if the selection in the fifth field is "Yes" then the last three also have to be selected using the list boxes.

Let us call the first four (textboxes) "mandatory-text1", "mandatory-text2", "mandatory-text3", and "mandatory-text4", the Yes/No selection list box "yes-no" and the optional selections "a", "b" and "c".

SO:

If mandatory-text1, or mandatory-text2, or mandatory-text3, or mandatory-text4, are blank, the processing php will abort.

However, if mandatory-text1, mandatory-text2, mandatory-text3, and mandatory-text4, are all filled in, the next check is to see whether the yes-no contains a "Yes" or a "No".

- If it contains a No, then a, b and c have to be necessarily left
  blank.
- If it contains a Yes, then a, b and c (list boxes) have to be
  necessarily selected.

With my level of proficiency in PHP, I have been able to reach this far:

```
    if ((mandatory-text1 || mandatory-text2 || mandatory-text3 == "") OR (yes-no == "Yes" AND (!(a || b || c  == ""))) {
    echo "blah" ;
    exit();
    }
    else {
    //do some stuff
    }
```

I haven't coded the 'do some stuff' part yet because when I try this code, I get the 'blah' message even when all the text fields are filled in, the yes-no is "Yes" and a, b and c have been selected.

I tried it first with a simple "||" for all the fields and that works fine - i.e. if even one of the fields is left blank I get the 'blah' message. I have also tried just checking for the yes-no and a,b,c and that too works fine i.e. if there is a Yes in the yes-no i get the blah if the a,b,c fields are blank.

But I need to satisfy all the conditions before I can proceed to the next step. The posts I have read here on SO brought me to the stage I am in right now. But none went to the level I want for my project.

Any hints for the logic would be appreciated!

Comment: is it  `$mandatory-text1` ?? or `'mandatory-text1'`

Comment: It is $mandatory-text1 - I checked out the original code. The mandatory-text is only a pseudo variable I used to explain the context here!

Comment: you have to be specific on what scenarios it is failing, from what i understood (yes-no == "Yes" AND (!(a || b || c  == ""))) should be (yes-no == "Yes" AND (a || b || c  == "")) for your case.

Comment: @ray I have not been able to get to that level of clarity yet! The code you see is what I have done so far. I am able to say only that I get the 'blah' message when I run the original code. I get a failure message (blah) even when all the fields have been filled. Will get back once I try Jim's suggestion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first of all, you are supposed to use $ before variable names

Second,
`mandatory-text1||mandatory-text2||mandatory-text3==""`
is wrong logic. It should be `$mandatory-text1=""||$mandatory-text2==""|| ...`

It works because `if(mandatory-text1)` alone means if mandatory-text1 is defined and not empty or null string, so in this case  `$mandatory-text1||$mandatory-text2||$mandatory-text3` alone is sufficient

```
if ((mandatory-text1 || mandatory-text2 || mandatory-text3 == "") OR (yes-no == "Yes" AND (!(a || b || c  == ""))) {
echo "blah" ;
exit();
}
else {
//do some stuff
}
```

same for a||b||c

Answer (score 1):

```
(mandatory-text1 || mandatory-text2 || mandatory-text3 == "")
```

This isn't working the way you think it is. This says:

if mandatory text 1 is not empty or mandatory 2 text is not empty or mandatory 3 text is equal to ''.

Try:

```
(mandatory-text1 == "" || mandatory-text2 == "" || mandatory-text3 == "")
```

Comment: So if I understand you right - the if statement I have written is doing what I want only for mandatory-text3 - right?

Comment: And - just a hint please - is it possible to perform all the checks in a single if statement? Or will I need nested ifs?

Comment: @vinaya Correct. You can use a single if statement but you can use nested ifs if you feel it will make the code easier for you to read.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it works in all scenarios. @Huge's suggestion also looks do-able. So though I am going to use your suggestion for now, I might go in for his as it might be better for maintenance.. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You may redesign your control in a more readable way, with a function or code block per field type, for example :

```
<?php


function checkFields( $data )
{
    // List of field to check
    $fields = array( 'mandatory-text1', 'mandatory-text2', 'mandatory-text3', 'mandatory-text4', 'a', 'b', 'c' );

    foreach ($fields as $field )
    {
        switch( $field )
        {
            case 'mandatory-text1':
            case 'mandatory-text2':
            case 'mandatory-text3':
            case 'mandatory-text4':
                if ( $data[$field] == '' )
                {
                     return false;
                }
            break;


            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
                if ( $data['yes-no'] == 'yes' && $data[$field] == '' )
                {
                    return false;
                }
                elseif( $data['yes-no'] == 'no' && $data[$field] != '' )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    // If we have not returned false so far, then all is clear
    return true;
}

// Usage :
if( checkFields( $_POST ) )
{
    // every thing is ok
}
else
{
    // bad submission
}
?>
```

You should mostly avoid 2 things here :

- Long AND / OR statements
- Repeating your self with the smae controls

Comment: I love this! @Huge... I started programming after (the age of) 48 and find getting my head around some concepts really tricky! Switch-case was one of them. I think I have finally understood it - thank you so much! I don't know whether I will use this in this project - but I'll definitely upvote it...

Comment: Is this correct? - function checkFields( $data ) // Usage :
if( checkFields( $_POST ) ) or is there a typo here?

Comment: Yes it is correct, $_POST is the variable provided by PHP with your inputed content. $data is an arbitrary name given to the function argument.
When you call chekFields( $_POST ), $data contains the value of $_POST inside the function (and does not exists outside the function).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, something like this should work. Do NOT use dashes in variable names.

```
if ($mandatory1 && $mandatory2 && $mandatory3 && $mandatory4)
{
    if ($choice == "Y" && $a && $b && $c)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
    elseif ($choice == "N" && !$a && !$b && !$c)
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
else
{
    // submission incorrect
}
```

Comment: (just to clarify) when you say if ($choice == "Y" && $a && $b && $c) am I correct in reading it as - $choice contains the value Y and $a, $b and $c contain some values? I am still learning and I find this if(something) slightly confusing!

Comment: Basically yes. `if ($a)` will be `true` if `$a` is not `null`, not an empty string, not an empty array, not the boolean `false`, and so on. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).